# Remove numbers and dots in column vector

Tags: r

I have a column vector and struggle to normalize it. It looks like this:

```
X2015.11.03.15.00.00.1
X2015.11.03.15.00.00.2
X2015.11.03.15.00.00.13
X2015.11.03.15.00.00.14
X2015.11.03.15.00.00.14
X2015.11.03.16.00.00
X2015.11.03.16.00.00
X2015.11.03.17.00.00
```

What I want to get is normalized TimeStamp:

```
2015.11.03 15.00.00
2015.11.03 15.00.00
2015.11.03 15.00.00
2015.11.03 15.00.00
2015.11.03 15.00.00
2015.11.03 16.00.00
2015.11.03 16.00.00
2015.11.03 17.00.00
```

So far I tried various combination of [Sub and gsub][1], but did not get to final result.

```
#remove X in Timestamp
x <- gsub("\\X", "", x)
#put space between time date and time
x <- sub("\\s+$", "", gsub('(.{11})', '\\1 ', x))
```

now it looks like this:

```
2015.11.03. 15.00.00.1
2015.11.03. 15.00.00.2
2015.11.03. 15.00.00.13
2015.11.03. 15.00.00.14
2015.11.03. 15.00.00.14
2015.11.03. 16.00.00
2015.11.03. 16.00.00
2015.11.03. 17.00.00
```

how to fix the rest? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `sub("\\.[1-9]+$", "", x)`

Comment: this fixes last digits with dot, but not this:                                                      
2015.11.03. 14.00.00.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `as.POSIXct` to convert to date time using a custom format, which is a better option than using regex in my opinion in this case, because the input is inherently a date time value:

```
df$V2 <- as.POSIXct(df$V1, format = "X%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S")
```

**Output:**

```
                       V1                  V2
1  X2015.11.03.15.00.00.1 2015-11-03 15:00:00
2  X2015.11.03.15.00.00.2 2015-11-03 15:00:00
3 X2015.11.03.15.00.00.13 2015-11-03 15:00:00
4 X2015.11.03.15.00.00.14 2015-11-03 15:00:00
5 X2015.11.03.15.00.00.14 2015-11-03 15:00:00
6    X2015.11.03.16.00.00 2015-11-03 16:00:00
7    X2015.11.03.16.00.00 2015-11-03 16:00:00
8    X2015.11.03.17.00.00 2015-11-03 17:00:00
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L
), .Label = c("X2015.11.03.15.00.00.1", "X2015.11.03.15.00.00.13", 
"X2015.11.03.15.00.00.14", "X2015.11.03.15.00.00.2", "X2015.11.03.16.00.00", 
"X2015.11.03.17.00.00"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```